# What resides inside the python self?

Tags: python

Recently I come across the following code in python

```
for var in self: 
    self.some_list.append(var)
```

I know little about self but the above code really made me to think so can some one explain me what the piece of code mean ?

Comment: Can you provide some more context?  What did it make you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over some object with the `for ... in ...` syntax, you are really calling the `__iter__` method of it. For example,

```
class Iterable(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.items = args 

    def dump(self):
        for val in self:
            print 'I have %s!' % str(val)

    def __iter__(self):
        for val in self.items:
            yield val

i = Iterable(1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'bar')
i.dump()
```

In the `dump` method the `for val in self` iterates over the `self.values` list as implemented by `__iter__`. If you drop the `__iter__` method, Python won't know what to do and you will get a TypeError ('Iterable' object is not iterable).

Answer (score 1):

The identifier `self` has no special meaning in python, it can hold whatever you put into it (either via an assignment or an argument of a function).

The only thing is that instance method when called will put the object on which the method was called as the first argument which is normally (by convention) called `self`.